# How can I place an object at the same distance between two others?

Tags: modeling

I want place usb between speakers (it has placed with random distance on image):
[image]

Comment: I started to answer this but I realized I need more details.  Are the circles and USB port separate objects, or are they all part of the same mesh.  What works for separate objects won't work if they're all part of the same mesh.

Answer (score 3):

Select both objects

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> -> Cursor to selected (moves the 3D-Cursor to the middle of all selected objects)

[image]

Select the object which should be in between

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> -> Selection to Cursor

[image]

Comment: Suggest it's the average of origins of selected objects.  In example above both cube origins are their centre of geometry, and hence the average is the middle.

Comment: This will only work if the circles and USB port are separate objects and have their origins set to the center of their geometry..  It won't work if they are part of the same object, even if they are separate meshes.

Comment: @MartyFouts: then he can select the corresponding vertices - works too. There are always exceptions...but since they have different colors, your assumption is wrong - i think ;)

Comment: If they're part of the same mesh, then snapping selected to cursor will collapse all of the vertices of the usb shape to the cursor's location.

Comment: yeah, that's right. Still i think your assumption is wrong. Let's wait what OP says.